# 500 error after wp_insert_post

Tags: wp-insert-post, 500-internal-error

The insert post works correctly, but then afterwards get a 500 internal server error for some reason, tested on a simple localhost site on my computer but error does not occur. :-

```
global $user_ID;

$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'My New Post',
    'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(0)
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Comment: have you try with default theme et all plugins desactivated ?

Comment: Yes deactivated all plugins, but still occurs. using 2017 theme.

Comment: a 500 error indicates something went wrong and to look at the error log, you should follow the usual debug process of checking PHP error logs for fatal errors and warnings, and turn on `WP_DEBUG`